# How reliable is the nodeValue property for stripping tags and how does it compare against strip_tags()?

Tags: php, html, dom

```
<?php
function walkDOM($node)
{
    if (! isset($node->childNodes))
        return;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $node->childNodes->length; $i++) {

        $childNode = $node->childNodes->item($i);
        $childNodeName = $childNode->nodeName;

        echo $childNode->nodeName . " - " . $childNode->nodeType . 
             " - \"" . $childNode->nodeValue . "\"\n";
        walkDOM($childNode);
    }
}

function processHTML($s)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $success = $doc->loadHTML($s);
    if (! $success) {
        echo "Load HTML failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    echo "Loaded HTML: " . $doc->saveHTML() . "\n";
    walkDOM($doc);
}

$s = '<div>hello, <p>world<big>!</big></p></div>';
processHTML($s);
?>
```

Output:

```
Loaded HTML: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>hello, <p>world<big>!</big></p></div></body></html>

html - 10 - ""
html - 1 - "hello, world!"
body - 1 - "hello, world!"
div - 1 - "hello, world!"
#text - 3 - "hello, "
p - 1 - "world!"
#text - 3 - "world"
big - 1 - "!"
#text - 3 - "!"
```

From the above code and output, we can see that when we access `nodeValue` property of any `DOMNode` we get its inner HTML with all tags stripped off. I can use this to filter out all tags as follows:

```
$s = '<div>hello, <p>world<big>!</big></p></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($s);
echo $doc->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue . "\n";
```

Output:

```
hello, world!
```

But I can do so using `strip_tags` as well:

```
$s = '<div>hello, <p>world<big>!</big></p></div>';
echo strip_tags($s) . "\n";
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I rely on this behavior of `nodeValue` property in future to strip tags or do any other kind of thing that I can imagine. Are there any hidden surprises?
2. How is using `nodeValue` to strip tags different from using `strip_tags()` to strip tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to strip tags, whay complicate? I think it is faster, and better to use the strip_tags() function. Also, it can take a second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped.

Comment: Do you have any source to backup your claim that it is faster and better to use the `strip_tags()`? Also, do you know the answer to my first question, i.e. can the behaviour of `nodeValue` that I have explained by relied upon?